# Como capturar ação do teclado sem pausar o programa C++?

Tags: c++

Como eu faço pra capturar uma ação do teclado sem pausar o programa?
Por exemplo:

```
char tecla;
do{
    scanf("%c", &tecla);
    printf("%c",tecla); 
}while(tecla != '0');
```

Eu queria que ele ficasse em loop, mas quando digitar algo no teclado conseguir capturar e executar uma determinada ação dentro do programa. O programa vai rodar no terminal, a cada loop e vou limpar a tela e imprimir outras coisas novamente.

Comment: trata com interrupção. O jeito de fazer isso depende da língua, seu programa é para rodar em desktop?. cria uma interrupção de teclado que execute algo quando for pressionada uma tecla. você ta usando c ou c++? assim que responder eu pesquiso e complemento a resposta

Comment: você pode postar seu código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível fazer isso com C++ puro, pois depende do sistema operacional e do console utilizado. ([Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/421871/1683070))

Uma alternativa é usar a função `kbhit()` disponível na biblioteca `conio.h`. Ela verifica se alguma tecla foi pressionada, então basta chaar a função antes de `scanf`. Porém, é preciso atentar porque existem implementações distintas para [Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libconio/) e [Linux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-conioh/). ([Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/422200/1683070))

No Windows, também é possível utilizar a função [`ReadConsoleInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para ler e esvaziar o buffer de input do console. Note que esta função também captura eventos de mouse, então é preciso verificar o [tipo de evento recebido](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683499(v=vs.85).aspx).

Uma consideração sobre tudo isso é que, dependendo do que você quer, não é bom fazer verificações em um loop. Isso desperdiça CPU. Uma abordagem para resolver isso é criar novas threads para fazer o processamento "pesado" e deixar a thread principal responsável por ler e escrever no console.

Comment: Foi o que eu achei tambem, pra mim não funcionou, estou usando MAC =\

Answer (score 3):

Achei nesse link a minha resposta

[kbhit](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/kbhit)

```
char tecla;
do{
if(kbhit()){
    tecla = getch();

    switch(tecla){
        case 'W': //cima
            break;
        case 'S': //baixo
            break;
    }
}
//executo meu programa bazeado na tecla
}while(tecla != '0');
```

A função `kbhit()` identifica quando ocorre alguma ação no teclado, porém ela está presente somente no header `<conio.h>` que foi feita exclusiva para o MS/DOS. Portanto não funciona caso esteja utizando um MacOSX.